# Elementos de uma Timeline quebrando linha

Tags: html, css, sass, scss

tudo bem?
Estou tentando fazer uma timeline com scroll, mas não estou conseguindo fazer com que os elementos da timeline entrem dentro da div ao atingir o tamanho máximo dela, para que assim essa parte não fique vísivel.
Aqui tem o código que tenho até agora, onde mostra o problema da quebra de linha que está ocorrendo!

https://codepen.io/Arthur_Oliveira/pen/GRKNGBb

```css
.timeline-background {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  padding: 0;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.list-items {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 37px;
  max-width: 440px;
}



.list-item {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  top: 0;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.list-items li {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.list-item li:first-child {
  position: absolute;
  left: 78px;
  top: 63px;
  cursor: pointer;
  list-style: none;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 3px solid #AD80FF;
  color: #D9D9D9;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.list-item li:last-child {
  position: absolute;
  right: -13px;
  top: 63px;
  cursor: pointer;
  list-style: none;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 3px solid #AD80FF;
  color: #D9D9D9;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.list-item li:last-child:hover {
  color: #FF04FF;
}

.list-item li:first-child:hover {
  color: #FF04FF;
}

.list-item .active {
}

.list-items li {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 50px;
  list-style: none;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 3px solid #D9D9D9;
  margin-top: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.list-items li.active {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 50px;
  list-style: none;
  border: 3px solid #FF04FF;
  background-color: #FF04FF;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.list-item li:first-child:after {
  cursor: initial;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 50px;
  margin-top: -6px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  height: 50%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #D9D9D9;
  z-index: 0;
}

.list-items li:after {
  cursor: initial;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 50px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  height: 50%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #D9D9D9;
  z-index: 0;
}

.list-item ul .actived:after {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #FF04FF;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center timeline-background">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <section class="list-items">
            <ul class="dots">
                <li class="active"><a class="item" href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a class="item" href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a class="item" href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a class="item" href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a class="item" href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a class="item" href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a class="item" href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a class="item" href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a class="item" href="#"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </section>
        <div class="list-item">
            <ul>
                <li class="d-flex d-sm-flex d-md-flex d-lg-flex d-xl-flex justify-content-center align-items-center justify-content-sm-center align-items-sm-center justify-content-md-center align-items-md-center actived" href="#list1"><i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-back"></i></li>
                <li class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center"><a class="item" href="#"></a><i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-forward"></i></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Eu tentei colocando um tamanho fixo pra div e usando overflow hidden, scroll e auto, mas continua o mesmo problema!
Se alguém tiver alguma ideia de como fazer isso e puder ajudar fico muito grato!
Desde já agradeço!!

Answer (score 0):

Olá, eu consegui resolver esse problema, vou colocar aqui o código pra poderem comparar com o que estava tendo problema, caso queiram!
Bom, o que eu fiz foi adicionar uma classe `backpage` com `position absolute`, `overflow auto` e um `width fix`o. Também mudei a `position` da class `list-items` para `absolute` e coloquei um `width maior` que o da `div` com a class `backpage`. Depois foi só arranjar a posição dos elementos!

Aqui o código final:

```css
.timeline-background {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  padding: 0;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.backpage {
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 450px;
}

.list-items {
  position: absolute;
  width: 2000px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

.list-item {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  top: 0;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.list-items li {
  position: relative;
}

.list-item li:first-child {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 63px;
  cursor: pointer;
  list-style: none;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 3px solid #AD80FF;
  color: #D9D9D9;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.list-item li:last-child {
  position: absolute;
  right: -13px;
  top: 63px;
  cursor: pointer;
  list-style: none;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 3px solid #AD80FF;
  color: #D9D9D9;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.list-item li:last-child:hover {
  color: #FF04FF;
}

.list-item li:first-child:hover {
  color: #FF04FF;
}

.list-item .active {
}

.list-items li {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 50px;
  list-style: none;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 3px solid #D9D9D9;
  margin-top: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.list-items li.active {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 50px;
  list-style: none;
  border: 3px solid #FF04FF;
  background-color: #FF04FF;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.list-items li:not(:last-child):after {
  cursor: initial;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 50px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 12px;
  height: 50%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #D9D9D9;
  z-index: 0;
}

.list-items li:first-child:before {
  cursor: initial;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 50px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: -53px;
  height: 50%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #D9D9D9;
  z-index: 0;
}

.list-items li:last-child:after {
  cursor: initial;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 50px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 12px;
  height: 50%;
  border-bottom: 2px dashed #D9D9D9;
  z-index: 0;
}

.list-item ul .actived:after {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #FF04FF;
}

.list-item ul .actived {
  color: #FF04FF;
}

.dots {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="d-flex d-xl-flex justify-content-center justify-content-xl-center timeline-background">
    <div class="backpage">
        <section class="list-items">
            <ul class="dots">
                <li><a class="item" href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a class="item" href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a class="item" href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a class="item" href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a class="item" href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a class="item" href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a class="item" href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a class="item" href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a class="item" href="#"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </section>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item">
        <ul>
            <li class="d-flex d-sm-flex d-md-flex d-lg-flex d-xl-flex justify-content-center align-items-center justify-content-sm-center align-items-sm-center justify-content-md-center align-items-md-center" href="#list1"><i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-back"></i></li>
            <li class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center"><a class="item" href="#"></a><i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-forward"></i></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Muito obrigado a todos que tentaram ajudar!!